# React-native --variant option

Tags: react-native, command-line-interface

What are the possible values for `--variant` option except for `release`? Where is it documented? I couldn't find in react-native docs.

Should I specify this option with `debug` or `devDebug` value for debug build?

thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are only two options. `release` and `debug`

The default `variant` is debug, so you don't need to set the `--variant` flag for it!

**Important**: `variant` is only available for Android (`react-native run-android`)

You could use `react-native run-ios --configuration Release` for iOS, or just change the XCode Scheme to `Release`

Comment: Thanks a lot! It's very confusing to see different names being used for different systems which essentially do the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

The `variant option` is available when you configure the `flavor` on the `android`.

- sample

```
buildTypes {
        debug {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
        release {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }
}

flavorDimensions "base"

productFlavors {
   dev {
     dimension "base"
     applicationIdSuffix ".dev"
   }
   prod {
     dimension "base"
     applicationIdSuffix ".prod"
   }
}
```

- cli

```
react-native run-android --variant devDebug
```