# How to create a custom build with React-Native?

Tags: react-native

I am learning about React-Native and while I am on the learning curve, I am trying to learn more about variants for different environments, especially for custom variants (like "development", "QA", "production", etc...), but I think I am not getting clearly the way that React-Native handles that.

In some tutorials that I have found, it seems that it is necessary to modify specific files for the Android build and other files for the iOS build, but I was expecting to have one unified way to set up that configuration and within the context of React-Native be able to change the environment variant and run it as equal no matter if it is for Android or iOS, without needing to change anything on specific files for each one (I mean editing a file without react-native tools).

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42833460/6674314) answer gave me a hint of what I am looking for, but still, I think I need a detailed explanation of how to use that (especially all the constraints that I need to be aware of).

So what I need to know is:

**Is it possible to create different custom variants with only React Native tools for both Android and iOS? If so, how?**

Just in case, here are the versions I have:

npm --version
6.14.10
npm view react-native version
0.63.4
npm view react version
17.0.1
npm view react-scripts version
4.0.2
npm view react-dom version
17.0.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I always used react-native-config library (https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-config) for setting up multiple environments. Basically you have to understand how they work for both iOS and android (it's not much complicated and you don't have to change a lot of things on native side) and afterwards you do your setup. If you search a little about this library and how you can use it, you'll get it work. It allows you to create how many custom environments you want because it relays on native tools